# GLSL Double Precision Angle, Trig and Exponential Functions Workaround

Tags: opengl, double, glsl, double-precision

In GLSL there's rudimentary support for double precision variables and operations which can be found [here](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/gpu_shader_fp64.txt). However they also mention "Double-precision versions of angle, trigonometry, and exponential
    functions are not supported.".

Is there a simple workaround for this, or do I have to write my own functions from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[this link seem's to be the best answer](https://www.thasler.org/blog/?p=93)

So yes, you'll need to make your own implementation for those functions.

[glibc source](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c;hb=HEAD) may be your friend.

Comment: That looks like it's going to be a dirty, dirty port... Thanks!

Comment: This link has GLSL source for double atan2 http://outerra.blogspot.cz/2014/05/double-precision-approximations-for-map.html

Comment: By 2020, the inevitable link decay has happened, which is why answers ought to quote relevant parts of what they link to.